# css values assignment to UpdateProgress in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updateprogress

I am using the following code to assign values to asp.net updateprogress control but having no luck

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var updateProgress=document.getElementById ('<%=UpdateProgressLinkActivity.ClientID%>');
   updateProgress.style.position='absolute';
   updateProgress.style.width='250px';
   updateProgress.style.height='100px';
   updateProgress.style.top='0px';
   updateProgress.style.left='0px';
  </script>
```

the control name is a copy paste.

Comment: specify above code with in a function and you may call that function on each update.

Comment: actually the element is happening to be null. checked with debugger. don't know why?

Comment: you check updateProgress value. it must be equal to any of id. if id is not present then it will show null. better you make alert with updateProgress

Comment: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewStories_ctl17_UpdateProgressLinkActivity   this client id is placed inside the getelementbyid function but still it can't get it.

Comment: i think no id is present in the name of updateProgress client id. can you give code for where the id is creating.

Comment: <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressLinkActivity" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity" DynamicLayout="True">
<ProgressTemplate>
<div style=" position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; background-color:white;" id="divLoading">
<img src="Images/loading25.gif" alt="Loading..." style="" />                                                             </div>                                                           </ProgressTemplate>                                                              </asp:UpdateProgress>

Answer (score 0):

You add this code in function and add this code on event (forexample onload)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function VisibledProgress()
{
   var updateProgress=document.getElementById ('<%=UpdateProgressLinkActivity.ClientID%>');
   updateProgress.style.position='absolute';
   updateProgress.style.width='250px';
   updateProgress.style.height='100px';
   updateProgress.style.top='0px';
   updateProgress.style.left='0px';
} 
 </script>
```

Your code Aspx :

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="VisibledProgress()" ..../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
var updateProgress=document.getElementById ('<%=UpdateProgressLinkActivity.ID%>');
```

or

use this:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress value="your getting cliend id" ID="UpdateProgressLinkActivity" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity" DynamicLayout="True"> <ProgressTemplate> <div style=" position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; background-color:white;" id="divLoading"> <img src="Images/loading25.gif" alt="Loading..." style="" /> </div> </ProgressTemplate> </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

specify value="your getting client id."

and use jquery -- var updateProgress = $("#UpdateProgressLinkActivity").val();

Comment: Hi, ClientID picks the value but it is wrong. when I checked with debugger the clientid was  ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewStories_ctl17_UpdateProgressLinkActivity but when I checked the id in browser then it was this ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewStories_ctl02_UpdateProgressLinkActivity

Comment: Can this be the problem of nested updatepanels.. I have nested the two updatepanels... I am going to repost. will post the link to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652827/issue-i-am-trying-to-assign-updateprogress-css-values-with-javascript