# Issue..I am trying to assign updateprogress css values with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updateprogress

I am trying to assign updateprogess css values with javscript but the clientID for the control is fetching wrong clientid.. the code of the asp.net is

```
<div style="display: Block; clear: left;" runat="server" id="DivLike">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelLike" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <div style="position: relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLike" runat="server" CommandName="<%#Eval("Like_Command") %>" Font-Size="XX-Small" OnCommand="LinkButton2_Command" Text="<%#Eval("Like_Command")%>">
               </asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
            <div class="popupstyle" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:none;" id="DivChapters" runat="server">
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                     <div>
                        Select Chapter:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListChapters" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        Select Topic:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTopics" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAddLink" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButtonAddLink_Command" Text="Add" CssClass="UtilityClass">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                     </div>
                     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressLinkActivity" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelLinkActivity" DynamicLayout="True">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                           <div style=" position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; background-color:white;" id="divLoading">
                              <img src="Images/loading25.gif" alt="Loading..." style="" />
                           </div>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdateProgress>
                  </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers>
                     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonAddLink" EventName="Command" />
                  </Triggers>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
         </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonLike" EventName="Command" />
      </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

the JavaScript code is this:

```
var updateProgress = document.getElementById('<%=UpdateProgressLinkActivity.ClientID%>');
updateProgress.style.position = 'absolute';
updateProgress.style.width = '250px';
updateProgress.style.height = '100px';
updateProgress.style.top = '0px';
updateProgress.style.left = '0px';
```

I have nested two updatepanels. Can this be the issue?

Comment: gonna guess that it's because the string "'<%=UpdateProgressLinkActivity.ClientID%>'" is not an actual id that can ever be on your page?

Comment: I coppied the client Id generated by Asp.net from the browser and pasted in the getelement("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewStories_ctl02_UpdateProgressLinkActivity"); but still does not work.

Comment: should have worked check that 1) no exact duplicate ID's exist in DOM and 2) make sure that you are not doing stuff inside iframes or things like that because if so it is still possible but in that case the context of the iframe has to be taken into account because an iframe is almost like another window inside your DOM and it is tricky to work with.

Comment: hi. Actually the control is inside the gridview row. sorry I did not mention that.